# Get date and time from date column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-date

I inserted date and time in database, now when trying to retrieve date and time both from database only getting time part.

I tried insert date using `TO_DATE('08/13/2019 09:10:03', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` into 'Time' col. Now trying to get date from table using `TO_DATE(Time, 'DD/MON/RR HH24:MI:SS')`, but only getting date part. My database nls date format is "DD/MON/RR". 'Time' col is date type and I'm using oracle 10g xe.

I can get date and time using `TO_CHAR(Time, 'DD/MON/RR HH24:MI:SS')` but as I need to use this in comparison operation like below:

`select TO_CHAR(Time,'DD/MON/RR HH24:MI:SS') from Table where (TO_CHAR(Time, 'DD/MON/RR HH24:MI:SS')  <= TO_DATE('08/07/2019 10:13:52', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))`

it gives this error 'ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string'. Also tried to use `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(Time, 'DD/MON/RR HH24:MI:SS'))`, still it gives only time part. Should I use TIMESTAMP datatype for 'Time' col?

I want to get date and time from table where i can use them in comparison operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date need not be converted into date again.

You can simply write your query like this:

```
SELECT
    TIME -- use to_char for formatting the output date
FROM Table
WHERE
    TIME <= TO_DATE('08/07/2019 10:13:52', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Cheers!!